# Does Malaki 3:16 & Tehillim 69:29 refer to the same Scroll (Sefer Zikaron = Sefer Chayim)?

Tags: jewish-books, tehilim-psalms, book-of-malachi

**Is the Sefer Zikaron from Malaki 3:16 the same Sefer Chayim from Tehillim 69:29?**

**[Malaki 3:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**

> "In this vein have those who revere the LORD been talking to one another. The LORD has heard and noted it, and a scroll of remembrance has been written at His behest concerning those who revere the LORD and esteem His name." ( אָ֧ז נִדְבְּר֛וּ יִרְאֵ֥י יְהוָ֖ה אִ֣ישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵ֑הוּ וַיַּקְשֵׁ֤ב יְהוָה֙ וַיִּשְׁמָ֔ע וַ֠יִּכָּתֵב סֵ֣פֶר זִכָּר֤וֹן לְפָנָיו֙ לְיִרְאֵ֣י יְהוָ֔ה וּלְחֹשְׁבֵ֖י שְׁמֽוֹ )

**[Tehillim 69:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.69.29?lang=bi)**

> "may they be erased from the book of life, and not be inscribed with the righteous." ( יִ֭מָּחֽוּ מִסֵּ֣פֶר חַיִּ֑ים וְעִ֥ם צַ֝דִּיקִ֗ים אַל־יִכָּתֵֽבוּ )

- Does Malaki 3:16 & Tehillim 69:29 refer to the same Scroll (Sefer Zikaron = Sefer Chayim)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems [Yehudah Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Eisenstein), at least, thought so, as he wrote in his [introduction to the Book of Chanoch](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_The_Book_of_Chanoch%2C_Introduction.3?lang=bi):

> "מחבר ספר חנוך...וכן בחבור "ספר השמים" עם יום הדין, "דינא יתיב וספרין פתיחין" הם בס׳ חנוך "לוחות השמים" לדין ומשפט, וכן באגדת חז״ל שלשה ספרים נפתחים בר״ה וכו׳, וכולם מיוסדים על הפסוק ימחו מספר חיים ועם צדיקים אל יכתבו, ונאמר ויקשב ה׳ וישמע ויכתב ספר זכרון לפניו

Translation: "The author of the Book of Chanoch...and also by connecting "The Book of The Heavens" with the day of judgement, "the Judge sits and the books are opened" which in the Book of Chanoch are the "Tablets of the Heavens" of judgement and law, and also in [the aggadah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.16b.12?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) of Chazal "Three books are opened on Rosh Hashana etc", and these [sources] are all based off of the verse "may they be erased from the book of life, and not be inscribed with the righteous", and so also it says "The LORD has heard and noted it, and a scroll of remembrance has been written at His behest"..."